# What is the definition of "dependent name" in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, name-lookup, dependent-name

In C++, the concept of *dependent names* is important because:

> Such names are unbound and are looked up at the point of the template instantiation ... in both the context of the template definition and the context of the point of instantiation

However, the only thing that the standard says is a dependent name is given in [[temp.dep]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#2), referring to unqualified function calls, basically in order to enable ADL to be fully effective for those function calls.

Are there any other dependent names besides those?

Consider some code like this, for example:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T t) {
    t.bar();
};
```

If one were to refer to `bar` as a "dependent name", would that be a technically *incorrect* use of the term, according to the standard?

Comment: [temp.dep.expr]/3 "An *id-expression* is type-dependent if..."

Comment: @M.M I do not consider that to be sufficiently clear (*i.e.*, that a type-dependent id-expression is a dependent name). I also don't think any of the cases in that paragraph applies to the `t.bar()` example.

Comment: [temp.dep]/2 also has *If an operand of an operator is a type-dependent expression, the operator also denotes a dependent name.* which should cover this case.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think so. `bar` isn't an operator, is it?

Comment: It is not, but `.` is.

Comment: @NathanOliver We don't have `operator.` in C++ yet, so I'm a little bit skeptical that that applies. I don't think the `.` refers to any name at all.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#3 suggests `.` is an operator, just one you can't overload.

Comment: @N.Shead I agree it is an operator, I just don't think it's associated with any name.

Comment: [temp.dep.expr/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#expr-5) specifies member access expressions, but I'm not sure about the "unknown specialization" part.

Comment: @Timo `t.bar` certainly is a member of an unknown specialization, thus `t.bar` is a *type-dependent* expression. Are we meant to infer from this that `bar` is a *dependent name*?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords , I "complained" aswell, and noted `"Of all the constructs that denote dependent types or expressions, a subset of them represent names. Those names are therefore "dependent names"`.

Comment: Granted, it's very unclear, because a dependent type is an evaluation step further away from a dependent name. In fact, a name might often undergo name lookup and then it turns out it refers to a dependent type, like in `template<class T> struct A { typedef T type; A<T>::type t; };`  here, `A<T>::type` is/refers-to a dependent type, but in order for this to be known, it necessarily is looked up in the template. So it cannot be a dependent name, afaics .. my C++ has become rusty :(

Comment: _Are we meant to infer from this that `bar` is a dependent name?_ No, do we need to? [There are special rules for dependent name resolution](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.res#1) and it seems they are only make sense for free functions, not class member access.

Comment: BTW, http://wg21.link/p1787r4 removes the term "a member of an unknown specialization" and makes such names dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Declarations and where to find them](https://wg21.link/P1787) being accepted into C++23, there is now an explicit enumeration of categories of dependent names, which seems to cover the code in the question.

In N4919 [temp.dep.general]/2 it is stated that

> [...] The component name of an *unqualified-id* (7.5.4.2) is dependent if
>
> - it is a *conversion-function-id* whose *conversion-type-id* is dependent, or
> - it is `operator=` and the current class is a templated entity, or
> - the *unqualified-id* is the *postfix-expression* in a dependent call.

And in [temp.dep.type]/5 the rules for when qualified names are dependent are given:

> A qualified name (6.5.5) is dependent if
>
> - it is a *conversion-function-id* whose *conversion-type-id* is dependent, or
> - its lookup context is dependent and is not the current instantiation, or
> - its lookup context is the current instantiation and it is `operator=`, or
> - its lookup context is the current instantiation and has at least one dependent base class, and qualified name lookup for the name finds nothing (6.5.5).

Regarding the example of `t.bar()` given in the question, the name `bar` is described in the referenced section (6.5.5) ([basic.lookup.qual]) as a "member-qualified-name". Furthermore, [basic.lookup.qual]/2 explains that its "lookup context" is "the type of its associated object expression (considered dependent if the object expression is type-dependent)". Clearly `t` is type-dependent, and it is the lookup context for `bar`, so [temp.dep.type]/5.2 applies, and `bar` is indeed a dependent qualified name.